# Move selected items from Listview to another one

Tags: c#

I am using one form with 2 listview ı want to move selected row from listview1 to listview2. How can I do that?

I've searched on Google and youtube but I can't reached any result about my probe.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr5Yd.png)

I wrote this but it does not work properly.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NqXEKkUiezP9DKpLO3urTVgi3PNLH4wq

Comment: You know how to add one so just add the one from the right and remove it there? What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NqXEKkUiezP9DKpLO3urTVgi3PNLH4wq

Comment: Please post the code in the question, don't just post pictures (btw you could also put those in the question instead of via google drive).

Answer (score 1):

To move items from one listView to another, you just need to add the item to the destionation listView and delete it from the source one.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach ( ListViewItem selectedItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
    {
        listView1.Items.Remove(selectedItem);  
        listView2.Items.Add(selectedItem);
    }

}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. Where is the i-variable? In the second code you're just adding and and removing every item in the listview, why - how does this help? In both you're only working on a single listview so where is the moving?

Comment: Now you've edited the code and removed the i-variable. But what is this code supposed to do now? You're just adding and removing the selected item which does absolutely nothing except waste a bit of time and ressources. Can you explain what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose, you can use Datagrid:

```
     dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToList())
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row.Cells[0].Value);
        }
```

Comment: I am not using datagridview its easy way I know  it. I want to that with Listview.https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NqXEKkUiezP9DKpLO3urTVgi3PNLH4wq

Comment: listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
                listBox2.Items.Add(item);

checkout these links
http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2014/05/transfer-listbox-items-to-another.html

http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2015/01/move-listbox-item-from-one-listbox-to.html

http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2014/05/how-to-addmove-multiselected-items-from.html

these will help you